# Running Gitlab Runner For Flutter Remotely

Tags: flutter, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a requirement to run a gitlab runner in aws , so everytime I push flutter code to gitlab I want the runner to catch it and then start the stages .